# understanding the usage of cudaMalloc to allocate a matrix

Tags: c++, cuda

While trying to understand how cudaMalloc() works for 2d matrix I came across the following post:

[Using cudaMalloc to allocate a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885195/using-cudamalloc-to-allocate-a-matrix)

I wanted to clarify some points of the answer given by talonmies hence created this seperate post.  Talonmies gave the following solution.

```
float **pa;
float **pah = (float **)malloc(pah, N * sizeof(float *));    
cudaMalloc((void***)&pa,  N*sizeof(float*));
for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
    cudaMalloc((void**) &(pah[i]), N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy (pah[i], A[i], N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
cudaMemcpy (pa, pah, N*sizeof(float *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

The code in line 5 :

```
cudaMalloc((void**) &(pah[i]), N*sizeof(float));
```

creates a block N*float space in device memory and put puts the starting address of the i-th block of device memory in pah[i]. pah[i] reside in the host memory, but the content of each pah[i] is the address of the memory created in the device.

Question 1> Is the above understanding correct ?

The code in line 6:

```
 cudaMemcpy (pah[i], A[i], N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

copies A[i] from host to the content of pah[i] (the content of pah[i] being the starting address of each of the N*float blocks).

Question 2> Is the above understanding of how the host memory gets copied to device memory correct ?

In order to access the (N,N) block of memory in the device (created by line 5 above) like a 2-d array we now need to copy the contents of all the pah[i]'s to a pointer in the device. So first N float pointers are created in the device by code in line 3. And then the address of the of the N*float chunks are copied from pah[i] to pa using code in line 8. After this we will be able to access contents of A[i][j]  residing in host with pa[i][j] residing in device.

Question 3> Is the above understanding correct ?

Now say I spawn N*N thread and change the content of pa[i][j] with the thread id of each of the threads. Then I want to copy back the content of pa[i][j] residing in the device to A[i][j] residing in the host. Will the code line below do the job, or am I making any mistake ?

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
  cudaMemcpy(A[i], pa[i], N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Thanks in advance to all who helps me to clarify these doubts/questions.

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question 1> Is the above understanding correct ?

Yes.

> Question 2> Is the above understanding of how the host memory gets copied to device memory correct ?

Perhaps.  I would say: "copies N*sizeof(float) bytes, starting at the (host) address contained in `A[i]` from host to the device, starting at the device address contained in `pah[i]`."

> Question 3> Is the above understanding correct ?

Yes, I might word a few things differently but the changes I might make seem minor.  I think you've got it.

> Will the code line below do the job, or am I making any mistake ?

It should be:

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
  cudaMemcpy(A[i], pah[i], N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

You are literally wanting to reverse the operation contained in line 6.
  Don't forget to use [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) any time you are having trouble with CUDA code.

Comment: thank you very much for your inputs/comments. I understand the mechanism much better now.